# Button used for navigation on Visualforce Page is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce

we have a button on visualforce page which has been called from community portal which is used to navigate from one visualforce page to other visualforce page with the help of the page reference class. The button is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser's javascript console (especially Network tab) to check if a request is being sent and what errors (if any) are returned.

Use Setup -> Debug logs, add the user to it, see if there are any errors in the debug log. If the page is exposed without login - you can still debug that, search for the special " Site Guest User" and add that to debug logs.

My gut feel - it's the security. Probably Profile(s) need access to Apex class acting as controller. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_guest_users.htm and https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_authenticated_users.htm